# Gradient light with Area light

Tags: node-editor, emission

I have just learned how to create a plan and make an emission of it, then create a gradient to control the light as I want. I was then advised that it should be possible to use nodes in an area light.

However, what I can't figure out is how I can, for example, see how my gradient looks (such as on my plane) when I apply the same principle to an area light?

Comment: Since lights have no directly visible geometry per-se the effects are only visible through the light effect on the scene (through diffuse influence, shadows, reflections etc.). If you require them to be visible, you are better off with an actual plane. Alternatively you can use the same node group on both a light and a plane to see the effect

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In _Cycles_ you can turn on visibility for lights in a way, see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the *Area* light visible for the camera, go to the *Object Properties* and under *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* enable *Camera*. This option is turned on by default for "normal" objects like mesh objects, but by default turned off for light objects. Note that it is only visible if the light is directed (at least partially) towards the camera - this goes for spot and area lights, point lights can be seen from any angle and sun lights look very weird. And it only works in *Cycles*, I do not know if there is an equivalent in *EEVEE*.

[image: ray visibility]

Comment: Nice one, wasn't aware of that

Comment: Thank you so much!!